# What do these IAR IDE icons mean?

Tags: ide, iar

Quick and easy question - if you know the answer. I can't find it mentioned in the documentation. What do the icons circled in red mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found in the built-in help (Workspace window):

The column  that contains status information about option overrides can have one of three icons for each level in the project:

Blank There are no settings/overrides for this file/group.

Black check mark There are local settings/overrides for this file/group.

Red check mark There are local settings/overrides for this file/group, but they are either identical to the inherited settings or they are ignored because you use multi-file compilation, which means that the overrides are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the icon itself, but the checkbox in that column indicates that a file (or folder) has an option override ([source](http://netstorage.iar.com/SuppDB/Public/UPDINFO/012120/arm/doc/infocenter/GettingStarted/CreatingAnApplicationProject/CreatingAnApplProj.ENU.html)).

[image]